express-session production latency issue with passport.js and render.com
It works in localhost, but in production the authentication is quite slow and takes at least a few seconds so the user still sees the 'login' page and then it magically 'jumps' to the site.
The app is a simple React/Vite SPA using Node.js, Express, Mongo backend. Basically a simple MERN stack.
My app requires user login for things like counting current users online, logging data, preventing abuse and so on. I chose Passport as the authentication library, with GoogleStrategy as the initial default I'm going to use.
Now, in order to actually keep a user's session persistent and keep them logged in for more than 1 hour without having to re-authenticate, I needed to implement express-session.
The GoogleStrategy is relatively straightforward, like this:
passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: `${SERVER_URL}/auth/google/callback`,
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, cb) => {
      const { error, user } = await createUserByProfile(profile);
      console.log("Passport received userId: ", user.userId);
      cb(error, user);
    }
  )
);

My basic setup is:

user goes to client site

user clicks to log in

authentication with Google account via Passport

user object retrieved and server redirects to /google/callback

either success or fail response to client, with user object in success case

keeping user object in state (avoiding local storage)

refreshing the client site re-authenticates automatically

logging out via a button destroys the session


The express-session, CORS setup is as follows:
const app = express();

app.set("trust proxy", 1);
app.use((req, res, next) => {  
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
});


app.use(
  session({
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl:
        process.env.MONGO_URL ||
        "mongodburi",
    }),
    secret: "secretstring",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "none" : "strict",
      httpOnly: true,
      maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    },
    name: "sessiondefault",
  })
);


const allowedOrigins =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"
    ? ["render's frontend url"]
    : ["http://localhost:5173"];

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: (origin, callback) => {
      if (!origin || allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
      }
    },
    methods: "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE",
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

I've set up the hosting via Render.com's Web Service and Static Site so that I can manage my front and backend via the same platform. So basically I've got my client/server URLs from Render, and I have localhost ports 5000 and 5173 respectively in local dev mode.
Environment variables are managed via Render's platform and Vite's .env files so that I use process.env. on the backend and Vite's import.meta.env. on the frontend.
This all works well in dev mode. This means that when logging in with localhost, I can see the session cookie being created in the Application tab in dev tools, and respectively in my MongoDB instance, and it persist on refresh/reload page and is deleted/destroyed when I log out.
Regarding the frontend part, I have a useEffect:
  useEffect(() => {
    const getUser = async () => {
      try {
        console.log("@ getUser");
        const response = await fetch(
          `${import.meta.env.VITE_APP_SERVER}/auth/login/success`,
          {
            method: "GET",
            credentials: "include",
            headers: {
              Accept: "application/json",
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
          }
        );

        if (response.ok) {
          console.log("User found. Logging in...");
          const userData = await response.json();
          userData.user.online = true;
          setUser(userData.user);
          setMessages(userData.user.adminMessages);
          await updateUserStatus(userData.user.userId, true);
          const { usersCount: numOfUsers } = await getUsersCount();
          setUsersCount(numOfUsers);
        } else {
          console.log("@ getUser response not OK");
          setUser(null);
          throw new Error(`Response not ok. Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (user) {
          console.log(error);
          setUser(null);
        }
      }
    };

    if (!user) {
      getUser();
    }
  }, [user]);

When I deploy and try this via the production mode, what happens is that the session cookie gets created on login, but I am immediately redirected 'back' to /login and only after about 4 seconds it basically gets the user data and completes authentication and redirects to the actual site.
Has anyone come across this issue in some way and knows how to pinpoint the source of the problem?
Render's event logs aren't completely "real-time" so I can't really understand from their logs what is going on. I'm guessing it's one of the following:

some terrible inefficiency in my frontend code

Render's hosting is slow and not compatible with this kind of setup

Authentication flow is too cumbersome to work fast on anything other than localhost

something else I missed


I've explored the cookie object settings for express-session via other posts and docs such as:

How to set up express-session in production. Express-session is not working in https

Why is this node.js app starting a new session on every page view in production, but not in my local environment?

Session with MongoDB Store not persisting after redirect

https://github.com/expressjs/session


Nothing suggets I made a mistake.

Debugging error handling and silent flows in the /auth router solved the issue, perhaps due to simply adding logs (which as far as I can tell sometimes helps).
router.get("/login/success", (req, res) => {  
  console.log("add log 1");
  if (req.user) {
    console.log("add log 2");
    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      message: "success",
      user: req.user,
    });
  } else {
console.log("handle failed user");
    res.status(401).json({
      success: false,
      message: "Authentication failed",
    });
  }
});

In addition I moved my MongoDB instance to be in the same region as the Render instance, but I also switched to a RedisStore solution instead of MongoStore since Render supports creating a Redis instance on their platform.
